# Directiva static - Métodos en Java llamados desde el main

Tags: java, método

¿Por qué no puedo invocar un método (perteneciente a la misma clase donde se encuentra mi método main) fuera del main sin la directiva static o protected?

Comment: Bienvenido sobre es.stackoverflow ! Podrias ser mas espcifico ? Tal vez ayudaria para darte una respuesta ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se trata de funciones o metodos estaticos (static), te dice lo siguiente: Este atributo/metodo pertenece a la **Clase** y **NO** al objeto. Para entenderlo un poco, aqui tenemos una clase basica llamada **Persona**:

```
public class Persona {
private String nombre, apellido;
private int edad;
private float estatura;
static String variableEstatica = "Soy una variable de la clase, es decir, "
        + "no necesitas declarar un objeto para llamarme!";

public Persona(){

}

public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido){
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public void setEdad(int edad){
    this.edad = edad;
}

public void setEstatura(float estatura){
    this.estatura = estatura;
}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido(){
    return apellido;
}

public int getEdad(){
    return edad;
}

public float getEstatura(){
    return estatura;
}

public static void holaMundo(){
    System.out.println("Hola mundo");
}
}
```

Nota que tenemos un atributo string y un metodo estatico en la clase. Que tal si intentaramos llamar un **get** dentro del metodo estatico?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De una vez nos muestra el error. Piensalo asi como que la clase **Persona** te esta reclamando y te esta diciendo **que dentro del metodo se esta usando algo ajeno que no es de el**. Y es porque ese **getter** le pertenece a **sus instancias**, mas no a su **clase**.(Veamos otro ejemplo creando un objeto en el metodo **main** para que tengas mas claro lo que te quiero decir)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tomamos la instancia de la Clase **Persona** (obj) y le añadimos un punto, vamos a ver que **no aparece ningun metodo estatico ni tampoco alguna variable** ya que simplemente, no le pertenece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Y que pasa si hacemos el mismo procedimiento, escribiendo *Persona.* ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si, vas ver el metodo y la variable estatica, **porque son de la Clase**.

Ahora, con el tema del modificador de acceso **protected**, te va a pasar lo mismo si no le añades **static** porque simplemente no le pertenece a la Clase.